# why does creating an object using Object('123') create a String() object but typeof is 'object'?

Tags: javascript

Do this:

```
var x = Object('abc');
```

now just type `x` in the console and click enter. It will output:

```
String {0: "2", 1: "3", 2: "2", 3: "3",....}
```

now type `typeof x`, you will get `object`.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Object constructor returns an instance of an object whose type is appropriate to the passed-in value. In your case, you pass in a string primitive value, so you get a String object back. (Note that in JavaScript string primitive values and String instances are two different kinds of values. It can be hard to tell because JavaScript automatically wraps string primitives in String wrappers when circumstances require it.)

The `typeof` operator returns "object" for String instances.

Comment: I noticed that `y = String('1212')` returns an object whose typeof is `string`.
So you can have a string instance of an Object constructor and also a string instance of a String constructor? And both are different types inherently?

Comment: @Ben no - the Object constructor is weird. It gives you back a String instance, not an Object instance. In other words, `Object("foo")` gives you exactly the same sort of result as `new String("foo")`.

Comment: @Ben I try to distinguish between the string primitive type and the String object type by using lower-case for the primitives and upper-case for the objects.

Comment: but the `typeof(String('dfdf'))` is `string` and `typeof(Object('dfd'))` is `object` so there has to be a difference.

Comment: @Ben oh sorry - I should have said that `Object("foo")` is the same as `new String("foo")` - the String constructor gives you back a string primitive value when you call it without `new`. (older comment edited.)

Comment: crazy :) but that's the answer! Thanks! will mark it as soon as i can

Comment: @Ben in that respect the String constructor is like the Number constructor - `String(123)` gives you `"123"`, while `Number("123")` gives you `123`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "";
```

is a primitive type String.

```
var x = Object('abc');
```

is an Object String.

Check the Type section for more : 
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf